# Error when making use of the server(usxampp) for my android application

Tags: android

When I try to use my xampp server on my real mobile device, the app which is user registration does not work. However, this works when I attempt to test it using android studio emulator. Additionally this error pops up when testing my app on a real mobile device:

> Register Error!
>
> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

Yes I am using my ip address in order to host the server, However I believe that this error is due to not having trusted certificates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please avoid using images, write the error message in plain text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android 9.0 in real device you need add explicit accessto apache HTTP client. Add these in your Manifest in  tag

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```